Ubuntu 24 and 22 only connecting to all repositories via mobile phone hotspot
Apologies if this question has been asked before, but I only seem to be able to get to some Ubuntu apt repositories via a mobile phone connection and I can't figure out why. They just don't like my IPv4 address and my landline connection. Could this be an IPv6/IPv4 issue?
The change is instant: switch on the ethernet port and connection refusals everywhere. Same result regardless of mirror.
Switch it off and go mobile hotspot only and everything it ticketyboo. shrug.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

You seem to have successfully demonstrated that your wired network is the problem. Your Ubuntu system works properly, as you demonstrated on a different network. Login to your wired router or gateway and look at those settings.
